# How do I implement a read / write client such as a POP3 client in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm not well versed in the art of node.js, so I'm not sure how to go about this: I want to write a client that can connect to a POP3 server and write to the server, and react to what ever the server sends back.

1. Open connection to server
2. Read server welcome
3. Send "USER some_user@domain.com"
4. Check for "+OK User Accepted"
5. Send "PASS mypassword"
6. Check for "+OK Pass Accepted"

If the server replies with anything but OK, trigger an error event.

What I have so far:

```
var   net = require('net')
    , sys = require('sys')
;

conn = net.createConnection(110, 'mail.somehost.com');
conn.setEncoding("utf8");
//1. Open Connection
conn.on('connect', function() {
    //2. Read welcome
    conn.once('data', function(data) {
        conn.pause();
        console.log('Server Welcome: ' + data);
        //4. Prepare to get response from server
        conn.once('data', function(data) {
            console.log('USER Response: ' + data);
        });
        //3. Send USER
        conn.write('USER some_user@domain.com' + "\n");
        conn.resume();
    })

});
```

Will the conn.pause, handle return, conn.once, conn.write, conn.resume sequence work for all of the interaction?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

As already stated, you should go with the following approach:

1. Write a basic parser for the protocol, you might end up with `data` only having the first 5 bytes of a line, you need to handle this without tons of duplication
2. The parser buffers the data and dispatches it to the different events
3. It will be fairly easy to add a `pause` function to the parser, if you really need that
4. Using the dispatch model in combination with a state variable your code will:

   A. Look way cleaner
   B. Be a lot easier to maintain
   C. You can, for example, send the `USER Response` and then let the `OK` handler method decide what it does based on the current state
5. This will overall reduce code duplication. Also what you're doing now is known as *Arrow Programming* (all your ifs/callbacks form an arrow)

**Old Answers**

The server waits for more data to come in, simply put, you need to end the line you send with `CLRF` aka. `\r\n`.

```
conn.write('USER some_user@domain.com\r\n');
```

Guess you should give the spec a read:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939

Also, your `.once` approach will very soon, get very complicated to maintain. I would instead use the normal `.on` event handling and have a state for the communication progress.

```
var state = 'CONNECT';
conn.on('connect', function() {
    conn.on('data', function(data) {
        // actually you should make sure that you got the COMPLETE message here
        // it may be the case that you only got half of it so check for CLRF
        // you should also buffer stuff after an incoming CLRF
        // best thing would be that you write a parser first that then dispatches the messages
        // to specific handlers
        
        switch (state) {
            case 'CONNECT':
                // blabla
                state = 'GETRESPONSE';
                break;
        
            case 'GETRESPONSE':
                // response
                break;
        
            case default:
                break;
        }
    })
});
```

Of course how you exactly implement this is left to you, you could just as well map the current state to a table of functions/methods which get that data and do something with it.

Comment: Thanx for your answer. I updated the question shortly after posting, as I saw that I didn't send the CRLF through. My main concern is how to handle the data coming back.